# Como incluir uma variável PHP dentro de um texto salvo no MySQl

Tags: php, variáveis

estou tentando inserir variáveis PHP dentro de um texto que é salvo no meu MySql, de forma que sejam lidos automaticamente na minha aplicação.
Primeiramente, vou explicar qual é minha realidade:

Página de impressão:

```
<?php
//PRIMEIRO, FAÇA A BUSCA POR ALGUNS VALORES DO BD.
//EXEMPLO: $variavel1, $variavel2, etc...
?>

//TEXTO PADRÃO EM HTML (para impressão):
// PERCEBAM QUE INCLUO AS VARIAVEIS PHP DENTRO DO TEXTO
Número do contrato: <?php echo $variavel1;?><br>
Nome: <?php echo $variavel2;?><br>
Endereço: <?php echo $variavel3;?>
//AQUI VAI O RESTANTE DO TEXTO DO CONTRATO ....
```

Ao invés de manter esse texto estático, de forma que eu só altero o valor das variaveis, gostaria de registrá-lo tambem no bd, de forma que fique mais facil para eu altera-lo. Ficando da seguinte forma:

```
//TEXTO SALVO NO BD:
Número do contrato: {contrato}
Nome: {nome}
etc...
```

DAI, quando eu for executar a aplicação, ele já carregue os dados automaticamente.

Desta maneira, eu conseguiria tanto alterar o texto, como também as variaveis de lugar. É possível?

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um template.

Basta apenas substituir as "tags" pelas variáveis.

Exemplo:

```
$texto_db = 'Número do contrato: {contrato}
Nome: {nome}
etc...';

echo str_replace(
    array(
        '{contrato}',
        '{nome}'),
    array(
        $variavel1,
        $variavel2),
    $texto_db
);
```

Comment: Oi Daniel, Entendi! No caso, essa é a forma mais indicada? Não existe alguma outra forma de interpretar automaticamente as variaveis sem precisar fazer a substituição?

Comment: E se eu não tiver o numero exato de variaveis, como posso fazer dessa forma?

Comment: A automação é trabalho do programador. rsrs Essa substituição do exemplo acima é uma forma "automática".
Quanto a quantidade de variáveis, não está descrito na pergunta. Mas não existe mágica. Você deve criar uma pré automação, montar algum padrão que facilite a rotina. O exemplo acima é meramente didático. Não quer dizer que é o melhor e tampouco a única forma de resolver.